# Drop items on items within Listview, how to get exactly drop position or index

Tags: android, listview, drag

I want to create an invetar app or something like this.

I have 2 ListViews and want to drag items from one List to the item of the Second List. So I need to know, where exactly the item will be dropped in the second list.

I am using a custom Adapter etc. but this is not the main question. My problem is, when I drag and drop using `setOnDragListener`, the listener just tell me, that I droped the item in the listview, but not where exactly. So I need to know the exact position or index where the item from list 1 has been dropped in the second ListView.

I tried to set listeners on the items inside the listview, but it does not work, because (I guess) the ListView is in front and the items are in the background so I can't do this and I have no idea how to solve this task.

[image: Task]

Comment: Give the code of  setOnDragListener in your Second list. Show code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was: my CustomAdaptor returned new RelativeLayout Object and I just added the OnDragListener in the CustomAdapter in the getView function.

view.setonDraglistener ....